# image truncated on mobile devices

Tags: css

for some reason my background image is getting truncated on mobile device.
here is the link https://2cm.es/sonews

```
.c-content-media-2{background-position:top!important;background-size:100% auto;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100% auto;height:100% auto;}
.c-content-media-2-slider .owl-controls{margin:0;position:absolute;right:30px;text-align:right;top:30px}.c-content-media-2-slider.c-pagination-bottom .owl-controls{bottom:20px;right:30px;top:auto}.c-content-media-2-slider .c-content-label{background-color:#32c5d2;color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;left:40px;padding:4px 10px 2px;position:absolute;text-transform:uppercase;top:25px;z-index:10}
/*@media (max-width:991px){.c-content-media-2,.c-content-media-2-slider{margin-bottom:20px}}.owl-theme .owl-controls{margin-top:10px;text-align:center}*/
```

Comment: I can,t see image in desktop also

Comment: it is there. pls refresh the page

Comment: as i tested this on android device and found this issue with only with google chrome mobile browser,  on MI Browser it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code of `.c-content-media-2` to the following:

```
.c-content-media-2 {
    background-position: top!important;
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The width and the height can't have: 100% auto; at the same time, it's either one or the other.

Comment: this does not help. as said , this issue on Google Chrome browser however in other browser full image is appearing but lot of empty space after the image. https://yourimageshare.com/ib/kFPPoO2WIw

Comment: If you change the `background-size` to `auto`, the image will display properly. Take a look: https://yourimageshare.com/ib/FSSGYTks8G